# I want to query a variable to compare it with values in influxdb

Tags: authentication, influxdb, influxdb-python

Here is the code. User entered values are stored in POST_USERNAME & POST_PASSWORD and I want to compare it with values in db and print them.

```
@app.route('/')
def log():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        return "Hello "

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def do_admin_login():
    POST_USERNAME = str(request.form['username'])
    POST_PASSWORD = str(request.form['password'])
    result=client.query("SELECT * FROM signup WHERE username = 
'POST_USERNAME'")
    return  '{}'.format(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `influxdb`is a good choice of technology for storing `credentials`. It is a `time-series` database and is designed to store point data for `measurements` like temperature. Basically things that are worthwhile displaying as statistics. You should not treat `measurement` as your regular relational database `table`.

As far as I am aware, `Influxdb` currently does not have the ability to `mask` values for `field` and `tag` values. Hence in security's perspective it is not wise to store your users `password` as plain text.

However, it does not mean that you can't outsource authentication to `influxdb`. That is, you don't store the credentials into a `measurement` but instead you create `influxdb` user accounts to represent your application's user account.

Then to authentication your users, instead of doing regular `SELECT` statement to do the usual `credential` validation, you'll make `HTTP` call to the `influx` server to authenticate.

However, unless you are looking for a quick win. I won't recommend going down this path as your `auth` functionality would basically be at the mercy of `influxdb`.

Refer to the link below to find out how authentication is managed in `influx`.

**References:**

Influxdb authentication: 
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/query_language/authentication_and_authorization/